# How to run a thread just after the previous one in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to execute two threads (runnable) in a specif order. In particular, I want that "first" is executed before "second". Here the code:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {


    MyFirstThread first = new MyFirstThread();
    MySecondThread second = new MySecondThread();

    new Thread(first).start();
    new Thread(second).start();

}
```

How do I fix my code in order to ensure that first will be executed before second? Thanks

Comment: There is no point in using two threads, if sequence of execution is important, just use one to do all the job, or don't use threads at all.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to run one thing after another, you are better off using one thread.

```
new Thread(() -> {
    first.run();
    second.run();
}).start();
```

You can add a `try/finally` block if you want to always run `second` even if `first` fails.

Answer (score 0):

> I want that "first" is executed before "second"

What do you mean, "executed before"?  Do you want them to have any overlap at all?  If not (i.e., if you want the first thread to *finish* before the second one starts) then see Peter Lawrey's answer.

But, maybe you want the "first" thread to complete some *part* of its task before the second thread starts to work.  That's a little bit un-clean because it means that the "first" thread is responsible for doing more than one thing, but perhaps you have a good reason.  In that case...

```
static Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

static class MyFirstThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        doStep1();
        semaphore.release();
        doTheRest();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    new Thread(first).start();
    semaphore.acquire();
    new Thread(second).start();
}
```